# MySQL query to concatenate data from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to retrieve data from the database.I have created a table vendor that includes vendor_name, vendor_code, etc,.

I wish to get the result in the exact way as given here
`vendo Ali Murtaza have 200 code` where vendo Ali Murtaza is the verdor_name and 200 is vendor_code

Answer (score 0):

Try the following MySQL query on Workbench.

```
SELECT CONCAT(vendor_name, " have ", vendor_code, " code.") from vendor_table;
```

Reference: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php